# How do I update all values under a column of a data frame if a specific condition is met?

Tags: pandas, rows

hi I have a dataframe and want to update the final column 'pos1' such that whenever the value under column 'sigc' is 1, it takes the value in column 'pos' all the way till value under column 'sigc' changes to -1, in which case the value of pos would be -ve of cell above.

please see the column['pos1']

so long story short - I have a table with columns 'Date' to column 'pos' and I want to add a column pos1 with values shown. How do it do that.

am assuming its a straight fwd pandas df operation

check column 'pos1' in the  below table

[image]

below are my codes but am a bit baffled that I have to use the last code twice to make it work
df['pos1'] = np.where(df['sigc'] == 1, df['pos'],np.nan)
                                                                                                                           df['pos1'] = df['pos1'].ffill()
                                                                                                                             df['pos1'] = np.where(df['sigc'] == -1, df['pos1'].shift() * -1, df['pos1'])
                                                                                                                          df['pos1'] = np.where(df['sigc'] == 0, np.where(df['sigc'].shift() == -1, 0,df['pos1'].shift()),df['pos1'])
                                                                                                                      df['pos1'] = np.where(df['sigc'] == 0, np.where(df['sigc'].shift() == -1, 0,df['pos1'].shift()),df['pos1'])

Answer (score 0):

So I created some random data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'flag': 1},{'flag': -1},{'flag': 0},{'flag': 0},{'flag': 0},{'flag': -1},{'flag': 1}])
>>> df['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(df))
Out[26]: 
   flag  value
0     1     27
1    -1     40
2     0     40
3     0      9
4     0     30
5    -1     88
6     1      3
```

Then, if it is 1, copy it over. If it is negative one, invert the last value and pull it forward. If it is still empty, forward fill the data.

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['flag'] == 1, df['value'], np.nan)
df['new'] = np.where(df['flag'] == -1, df['new'].shift() * -1, df['new'])
df['new'] = df['new'].ffill()
```

This yields:

```
Out[37]: 
   flag  value   new
0     1     27  27.0
1    -1     40 -27.0
2     0     40 -27.0
3     0      9 -27.0
4     0     30 -27.0
5    -1     88 -27.0
6     1      3   3.0
```

Comment: thanks, that was very useful but I realised the table didn't capture one more condition, I have updated the table now. the additional condition is, if value of 0 in 'sigc' follows -1 then 'pos1' should be 0. for example see the sequence 26/10 to 29/10.

Comment: just below the table I have used your codes and added a few of mine. what confuses me is that I have to use the last code twice and only then it works.